# Json присоединение элементов

Tags: javascript

Вопрос вроде бы простой, но что-то погуглив и попробовав разные методы и из-за плохого знания js совсем запутался.
Имеется нотация:

```
{action:"someAction",data:info}
```

где info надо заполнить в цикле элементами ключ:значение. Как это выразить в нотации? Как присоединять элементы как в php?

```
 array["key"]=value
```

p.s. Подключен JSON2.js

**UPD**
Уточню вопрос, как динамически добавлять к объекту свойства имя которого содержится в постоянно меняющейся в цикле переменной?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо это массив, и тогда понятия **ключ:значение** в обычном понимании нету:

```
res = [ el1, el2, el3 ];
```

И тогда добавляем так:

```
res.push( el4 );
//На крайний случай, но лучше не велосипедничать
res[ res.length ] = el4;
```

Либо-же это объект:

```
res = {
  key1: val1,
  key2: val2
};
```

И добавляем так:

```
res[ key4 ] = val4;
```

Answer (score 1):

Все извиняюсь вопрос действительно очень глуп, обычное незнание синтаксиса, но вдруг кому-нибудь будет полезно:

```
var info=Object();

info[key]=value; //Добавление свойств объекта аналогично ассоциативному массиву в php

{action:"someAction",data:JSON.stringify(info)} //Здесь используем stringify для конвертации объекта в json
```

Comment: вместо Object используйте {}

Comment: ММ в чем разница?

Comment: В профессиональности кода...

Да и если уже используете object - пишите `new Object()`, тогда в это есть хоть какой-то смысл( хотя вам он точно ненужен ^^ )